# Can't set Post ID properly

Tags: posts

I'm trying to generate posts based on a JSON document. I'm stuck at the trying to assign the ID from the json document to the post's wordpress ID. I read on here that the way of going about this is though setting an 'import_id' on `wp_insert_post`

```
$json = json_decode("{
        \"tt1412213\":{
           \"title\":\"Movie\",
           \"rating\":\"excellent\"
        }
    }", true);

foreach($json as $item) { 
    $itemID = array_keys($json, $item);
    if (get_post_status( $itemID ) == false ) {
        if($item["title"] and $item["rating"]){
            global $user_ID;
            wp_insert_post(array(
                'post_title' => $item["title"],
                'post_content' => $item["rating"],
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                'post_author' => $user_ID,
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'post_category' => array(0),
                'import_id' => $itemID
            ));
        }
    }
}
```

I would like my post to have the ID `tt1412213` but it defaults to a number instead. Anything I'm missing?

Comment: The db schema for WP says ID is a Big Int number, look into e.g. post meta instead for storing post related stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**'import_id'**
(int) The post ID to be used when inserting a new post. If specified, must not match any existing post ID. Default 0.

Accordingly to the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/), the ID needs to be an integer.
So no letters are allowed unfortunately.

Comment: Ah, well. I see. Thank you.